# c++ : target of instance of std::function returns null pointer

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

The following code compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef void (*f_type) (int a);

void say(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << "!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    int a=5;

    say(a);

    std::function<void(int)> fn{say};
    f_type fn_pointer = fn.target<void(int)>();
    
    if(fn_pointer)
        fn_pointer(a);
    else
        std::cout << "null ptr" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but when executed prints:

```
5!
nullptr
```

I would like to understand why target returned an empty ptr, and not a pointer to the function "say".

note : it compiles for c++ up to c++14, for c++17 onward, compilation fails with error (which is cryptic to me):

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:58:0,
                 from main.cpp:11:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h: In instantiation of ‘_Functor* std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::target() [with _Functor = void(int); _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {int}]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',28)">main.cpp:28:46</span>:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:733:9: error: invalid use of const_cast with type ‘void (*)(int)’, which is a pointer or reference to a function type
  return const_cast<_Functor*>(__func);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: It's not compiling for me. [code](https://godbolt.org/z/KvaT46) It's not compiling in c++11 [either](https://godbolt.org/z/vxf79e).

Comment: @cigien just checked, it is compiling for c++14, but not for newer version

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am afraid i will not give a thrilling answer: whatever onlinegdb uses (https://www.onlinegdb.com/) (could not find details).

Comment: I'm going to assume that this is a bug, since compilers don't allow it now (with the same language version).

Comment: I've attempted it on VS2017, x64 debug build, v141 tool chain set to C++17, and can, indeed, reproduce `fn.target` returning null, on the code from the original post without any modifications. Apparently, we all just missunderstand how it works, sec, will post a modified example that doesn't return null.

Comment: There is a nice example on cppreference [std::function<R(Args...)>::target](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target) that would be more helpful for development of you experience than asking questions on SO.

Comment: its in their [faq](https://www.onlinegdb.com/faq), it is g++ 5.4.1 (for both c++14 and c++11) which is rather old

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reproduced it on VS2017, seems like the `target` method returns a **pointer to pointer** (as in returning a pointer to the actual function pointer stored in the object), and expecting its template type argument accordingly. Here is a modified example that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef void(*f_type) (int a);

void say(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << "!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    int a = 5;

    say(a);

    std::function<void(int)> fn{say};
    f_type* fn_pointer = fn.target<void(*)(int)>();

    if (fn_pointer)
        (*fn_pointer)(a);
    else
        std::cout << "null ptr" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Confirmed `target` returning a pointer to the actual function pointer by running the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef void(*f_type) (int a);

void say(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << "!" << std::endl;
}

void say_boo(int a)
{
    std::cout << "booooo" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    std::function<void(int)> fn{say};
    f_type* fn_pointer = fn.target<void(*)(int)>();
    (*fn_pointer)(a);
    fn = say_boo;
    (*fn_pointer)(a);
    return 0;
}
```

This produced the following output:

```
5!
booooo
```